# I want to create an international export shipment using UPS API

Tags: api, ups

I want to create an international export shipment using UPS API. I'm creating the post tag, but somehow I can't create the documents and forms part. I have tried to fill in the InternationalForms fields as much as possible. What is missing?

How can I edit the json structure to render the forms. Import invoice should be created by UPS company under normal conditions, it occurs when I create a cargo shipment manually, but I could not do it with api. Can you please help. Thanks

```
{
  "ShipmentRequest": {
    "Shipment": {
      .....
      },
      "ShipperNumber": "accoundid",
      "Address": {
        ......
      },
      "Service": {
        "Code": "65",
        "Description": "UPS Worldwide Saver"
      },
      "NumOfPiecesInShipment": "1",
      "Package": {
        "UnitPrice": "1",
        "Dimensions": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "CM"
          },
          "Length": "30",
          "Width": "30",
          "Height": "5"
        },
        "Packaging": {
          "Code": "02",
          "Description": "package"
        },
        "DimWeight": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "KGS"
          },
          "Weight": "1"
        },
        "PackageWeight": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "KGS"
          },
          "Weight": "1"
        },
        "PackageServiceOptions": {
          "DeclaredValue": {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
            "MonetaryValue": "59"
          }
        }
      },
      "PaymentInformation": {
        ......
          }
        }
      },
      "InvoiceLineTotal": {
        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
        "MonetaryValue": "59"
      },
      "Shipper": {
        ......
        },
        "ShipperNumber": "accound id",
        .....
        }
      },
      "ShipTo": {
        "Name": "UPS TEST",
        "AttentionName": "GERMANY TEST",
        "Phone": {
          "Number": "00000000000"
        },
        "TaxIdentificationNumber": "tax number",
        "Address": {
          "AddressLine": "address",
          "City": "SEA CLIFF",
          "StateProvinceCode": "NY",
          "PostalCode": "11579-1221",
          "CountryCode": "US"
        }
      },
      "ShipFrom": {
        "Name": "comopany name",
        "AttentionName": "author",
        "Phone": {
          "Number": "phone"
        },
        "TaxIdentificationNumber": "tax",
        "Address": {
          "AddressLine": "address",
          "City": "cty",
          "StateProvinceCode": "st",
          "PostalCode": "pc",
          "CountryCode": "count"
        },
        "VendorInfo": {
          "VendorCollectIDTypeCode": "0356",
          "VendorCollectIDNumber": "IMDEU1234567",
          "ConsigneeType": "02"
        }
      },
      "Description": "product desc",
      "InternationalForms": {
        "FormType": "09",
        "CN22Form": {
          "LabelSize": {
            "Code": "1",
            "Description": "Large"
          },
          "LabelPrintMethod": {
            "Code": "G",
            "Description": "Laser"
          },
          "CN22Content": [
            {
              "CN22ContentType": {
                "Code": "2",
                "Description": "Gift"
              },
              "CN22Quantity": "1",
              "CN22Weight": {
                "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                  "Code": "KGS"
                },
                "Weight": "1"
              },
              "CN22Value": {
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "MonetaryValue": "59"
              },
              "CN22CountryOfOrigin": "TR",
              "CN22Description": "product des"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "ShipmentRatingOptions": {
      "RateChartIndicator": "0"
    },
    "LabelSpecification": {
      "LabelImageFormat": {
        "Code": "PNG",
        "Description": "PNG label"
      },
      "HTTPUserAgent": "Mozilla/4.5"
    }
  }
}
```